How to make a borderline for the bottomAppBar with FAB?
I create a border for the bottomAppBar with floatingActionButton in Flutter, with shapeNotched, but
border doesn't follow for the shapeNotched line, it goes strait instead
I try to make a border but it doesn't work how i expected
enter image description here
my code below
enter code here
  bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30),
    child: CustomBottomAppBar(
      notchMargin: 8.0,
      fabSize: 56.0,
      onItemTapped: _onItemTapped,
      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
    ),
  ),

some rules of Stackoverflow doesn't let me paste other part of a code
I cant understand what ecsactly

Can you share image? What is expected and How it shows

Please add images for expected behaviour and what you have achieved.

@NipulRathod I've edited my post and added a picture link
My menu doesn't have a border near the FloatingActionButton, so that the problem is

@AkshayGupta I've edited my post and added a picture link
My menu doesn't have a border near the FloatingActionButton, so that the problem is

Ok got it what you expected but as i mentioned please attach what you have achieved as well as the code you have used.
